# How to permanently enable immersive mode

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I was doing some tests with immersive mode in andriod.
The only problem is that the immersive mode is automatically exited when I exit the app.
Is there any way so that the immersive mode is not disabled on the pausing of activity(when the user presses home).
Will it work if I do it inside a service or something ?

Comment: Since a `Service` is UI-less I don't see how you relate that to immersive mode. What are you actually trying to achive? That your `Activity` automatically will enter immersive mode the next time it's started?

Comment: Just that it should not exit the immersive mode on exit. Is it possible anyhow ?

Comment: It's a setting for views within _your_ app. Other apps should decide for themselves whether or not they want to use immersive mode for their content.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Have a Full-Time-Immersive mode?! Why?!